# Get Serial Number of physical drive using win32_diskDrive api in vc++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to get the serial number of Physical Drives which attached externally to my system with USB. Now when I am trying to get the serial number, It gives the serial number of Physical Drive attached by SATA cable. It gives the serial number in encrypted form. But when I am trying for external drives. It does not give the correct serial number.

I am doing this by `win32_DiskDrive` winapi.

I am using this code.

```
       void GetDrives()
        {
            HRESULT hres;    // The return result of COM
            ULONG uReturn = 0;
            int nIndex = 0;
            CString szVariantString;
            CString szSerialNumber;
            VARIANT vtProp;

            hres =  CoInitializeEx(NULL,COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED); 

            if (FAILED(hres))
            {
                return;                  // Program has failed.
            }

            IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
            hres = CoCreateInstance(
                CLSID_WbemLocator,             
                0, 
                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

            if (FAILED(hres))
            {
                CoUninitialize();
                return;                 // Program has failed.
            }

            IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

            // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
            // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
            // to make IWbemServices calls.
            hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
                _bstr_t("ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
                NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
                NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
                0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
                NULL,                    // Security flags.
                0,                       // Authority (e.g. Kerberos)
                0,                       // Context object 
                &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
                );


            if (FAILED(hres))
            {
                pLoc->Release();     
                CoUninitialize();
                return ;                // Program has failed.
            }

            hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
                pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
                RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
                RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
                NULL,                        // Server principal name 
                RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
                RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
                NULL,                        // client identity
                EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
                );

            if (FAILED(hres))
            {
                pSvc->Release();
                pLoc->Release();     
                CoUninitialize();
                return;               // Program has failed.
            }

            IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
            hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
                bstr_t("WQL"), 
                bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive"),
                WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
                NULL,
                &pEnumerator);


            IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = nullptr;
            CString szDisk;
            if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
            { 
                while (pEnumerator)
                {
                    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
                    if(!uReturn)
                        break;


                    // Variant is always needed to clear as it was initialized with new values
                    VariantInit(&vtProp);
                    memset(&vtProp,0,sizeof(VARIANT));

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    VariantClear(&vtProp);

                    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
                    if(&vtProp != NULL)
                    {
                        szVariantString = vtProp.bstrVal;
                        szVariantString.ReleaseBuffer();
                    }


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    VariantClear(&vtProp);
                    nIndex++;
                }
            }

            if(pSvc)
                pSvc->Release();
            if(pLoc)
                pLoc->Release();
            if(pEnumerator)
                pEnumerator->Release();
            if(pclsObj)
                pclsObj->Release();

            CoUninitialize();
        }
```

I took the help of msdn:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx
```

Can anyone  help me.

Comment: Can you give us some code that you're currently using? [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be nice. We can't help you to find out what you're doing wrong (if anything), unless we can see what you're doing.

Comment: ReleaseBuffer() makes no sense.  Use the WMI Code Creator utility to double-check queries.  Don't expect miracles from flash drives and keep in mind that serial numbers are very trivially changed.  Also the OS version matters, old ones don't work and (I think) win8 reverse the number.

Comment: I tried this thing many times. Thats why I am asking. It gives the flash drives serial number. So why not if external hard drives.

Comment: FWIW, the "encrypted" from is just HEX. Have you tried a tool like WMIExplorer or WMIC to see if you get the desired results from your external device(s)?